# How can I monitoring a flask app without modifying his code?

Tags: python, flask, prometheus

I've been making a little system to monitoring a flask app and others (postgres database, linux server, etc) with prometheus. Everything is going well, but I would like monitoring my flask app without modifying the code.

For example to monitoring methods of my app I did:

```
# Create a metric to track time spent and requests made.
REQUEST_TIME = Summary('request_processing_seconds', 'Time spent processing request')

@app.route('/')
@REQUEST_TIME.time()
def index():
 myUser = User.query.all()
 return render_template('add_user.html', myUser= myUser)
```

I used [this](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python) python library.

Also, I used [other library](https://github.com/sbarratt/flask-prometheus) to monitoring a flask app:

```
monitor(app, port=9999)
```

unfortunately both are modifying my code. I want to monitoring my flask app without modifying his code. It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

It really isn't clear what you're asking. However, if you just need info about which requests are called and how long they take, you could run your flask app with newrelic: they offer a free tier (yay!) and using it you will gain lots of insight about your app. however to use it you'll need to run your app with their client (but no code changes are required).

more info on what you'll get can be found here:
https://newrelic.com/python/flask